# Is there an optimal way to swap fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

[image: table]

I don't want to make many queries to my database.
How can I change the "position" field in places.
For example:

[image: table data]

[image: updated table data]

How can this be done in one request?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Hi - if Position is an attribute of the record (i.e. it is a column) then how are you expecting it to change - without updating the table?

Comment: Essentially you want to renumber the rows using the column `position`. What's the rule for the new ordering? Is it ascending or descending?

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by:

```
UPDATE lessons l 
SET position = data.position 
FROM ( VALUES ${IdsWithPositions} ) AS data(id, position) 
WHERE l.id = data.id
```

Where IdsWithPositions  =>
array is cast to the form - (id, position), (id, position)

Comment: It is still unclear how you solved this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).